# What is the difference between calling method using object and without object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Case 1- This code working fine (show1.rb)

```
class MyShow
  def pick
    show
  end

  def show
    puts "Showing some data"
  end
end

obj = MyShow.new
obj.pick
```

Case 2- This code generating error (show2.rb)

```
show  

def show
  puts "Showing some data"
end
```

So why it's working fine in first case when I am calling a method before defining it, but in second case it generating error.

Comment: Because you're calling the method before defining it in the second case. Try calling it on the last line

Comment: @Виктор But in first case I am also calling the show method before defining it... see the pick method.

Comment: In the first case, you are calling it _from the last line_. Actually, `obj.pick` calls it, implicitly.

Comment: You neglected to say what the error message was and where it occurred. It was, `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'show' for main:Object)` and it occurred when the line `show` was being executed. (The location is given in the error message.) This pinpoints the problem. You need to pay close attention to the content of error messages (and include them when relevant in SO questions).